# Reference error is not defined on application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When trying to submit data on a form, the webserver is giving me an error saying **Reference error: Item is not defined**, but based on my code, everything looks okay to me. Is there anything that stands out to you in my code that might cause this?

I was playing around with the Const, but I'm not sure if that's where the problem lies.

Here's my Javascript file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//specify where to find the schema
const Items = require('./models/item')
// connect and display the status 
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/items', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => { console.log("connected"); })
  .catch(() => { console.log("error connecting"); });

// use the following code on any request that matches the specified mount path
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   console.log('This line is always called');
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); //can connect from any host
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS'); //allowable methods
   res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});
app.get('/items', (req, res, next) => {
  //call mongoose method find (MongoDB db.Items.find())
  Items.find()
    //if data is returned, send data as a response 
    .then(data => res.status(200).json(data))
    //if error, send internal server error
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error: ${err}');
      res.status(500).json(err);
    });
});

  // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// serve incoming post requests to /items
app.post('/items', (req, res, next) => {
// create a new item variable and save request’s fields 
const Items = new   items ({
  itemName: req.body.itemName,
  servings: req.body.servings
});
//send the document to the database 
Items.save()
  //in case of success
  .then(() => { console.log('Success');})
  //if error
  .catch(err => {console.log('Error:' + err);});
  });


//to use this middleware in other parts of the application
module.exports=app;
```

Comment: Usually, errors show stack trace and line number & filename where the error has occurred. Can you share that information also?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for replying. Error is at app.js:41:15

Comment: This is my app.js file that's above

Comment: There's no reference to `item` anywhere in your code. Line 41 is `const Items = new   items ({` it says `items`, not `item`.

Comment: Earlier you defined `const Items = require('./models/item')`.  So I think it should be `new Items`, not `new items`. And you can't redefine a `const`, so you need to use a different variable for the instance.

Comment: Hi Barmar! Thank you, so I fixed that and now it's saying TypeError: Items.save is not a function. I decided to use 'items' as the new variable.

Comment: did you turn `const Items` to `const items`? Change the `const` into a `var` or `let`

Comment: Hello Kino, if I change it to const items, it causes an issue with the app retrieving data from mongoDB, so the const Items works better it seems. I'm just having issues with the function error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.post('/items', (req, res, next) => {

// Items already defined
const items = new Items({
  itemName: req.body.itemName,
  servings: req.body.servings
});

items.save()
  //in case of success
  .then(() => { console.log('Success');})
  //if error
  .catch(err => {console.log('Error:' + err);});
  });
```

Items constant is already declared, and you trying to re-declare it

Comment: you forgot about the closing bracket